# Eager load service worker from WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, service-worker, amp-html, progressive-web-apps

You know how you can preload/install the service worker of your PWA from your AMPs using [amp-install-serviceworker](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-install-serviceworker/)?

I want the same from my WordPress site. I want it to be able to preload my PWA's service worker when user visits a page from it.

- My WordPress site is on a sumbdomain: sub.example.com
- My PWA lives on the domain: example.com
- My PWA service worker lives in: example.com/sw.js

When the user visits a page from the WP site: **sub.example.com/some-page**, I want the **example.com/sw.js** to be installed. Just like with AMP.

Comment: Have you checked this documentation of [Wordpress Super Progressive Web Apps](https://wordpress.org/plugins/super-progressive-web-apps/)?

Comment: @jess it turns the wordpress site into a PWA. So it's not what I'm looking for. But thanx.